# My code's not working

Tags: javascript

```
I'm beginning javascript and i do some exercise to train my self, but i've a 
problem.
My code had to ask the time to the user and give the time one seconde after 
the time entered.
And my code shows my always "temps erroné" (that mean ~wrong time).
Here's my code :
```

> That ask to user the time

```
var hour = Number(prompt("heure actuelle?"));
var minute = Number(prompt("minute actuelle?"));
var seconde = Number(prompt("seconde actuelle?"));
```

> //this function is like a control, if the time entered is wrong the function 
>   is false

```
 function isTimeValid(hour, minute, seconde){
  if((hour >= 24) || (hour < 0)) {
  return false
  }
  if((minute < 0) || (minute >= 60)) {
   return false
  }
  if((seconde >= 60) || (seconde < 0)) {
  return false

  }
  else {
    return true
  }
}
```

> This function modify the time

```
function displayNextHour(hour, minute, seconde){
if((seconde >= 0) && (seconde < 59)) {
  seconde++;
} else if(seconde === 59) {
  seconde = 0
  minute++
  }
if(minute === 60) {
  minute = 0
  hour++
  }
if(hour === 24) {
  hour = 0
  }
 var time = "Il est " + hour + "h " + minute + "m " + seconde + "s";
 return time
}
```

> The last part lunch function

```
if(isTimeValid()){
 console.log(displayNextHour(hour, minute, seconde))
}else{
  console.log("temps erroné")
}
```

So if you can help me that will be very helpful for me in my javascript learning :D

Comment: Please consider choosing a relevant title, as well as using the relevant tags .

Comment: Java != javascript

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass arguments to the function

Replace

```
if(isTimeValid())
```

with

```
if(isTimeValid(hour, minute, seconde))
```

Comment: Thank you man :D It's a stupid mistake ^^
I've read my code again and again, but i didn't see it x)

Comment: welcome)) The stupid mistakes causes the most biggest problems )) I did it many times. Please, mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass arguments like Mike said and there is another mistake in your code.
You control the hours (=24) and minutes (=60) in "isTimeValid" but the next 
function has errors in control this parameters. The code below fix it.

```
function displayNextHour(hour, minute, seconde){
 if((seconde >= 0) && (seconde < 59)) {
  seconde++;
} else if(seconde === 59) {
  seconde = 0
  minute++
  }
if(minute === 59) {
  minute = 0
  hour++
  }
if(hour === 23) {
  hour = 0
  }
 var time = "Il est " + hour + "h " + minute + "m " + seconde + "s";
 return time
}
```